# R- Creating New Variable Based on Dupication of Patient Admission Based on Values in a Different Row

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, tidyr

I have a dataset that is looking at admissions to hospital. Each patient has an admission time (`adm_time`) and a discharge time (`dc_time`). To analyse the data, I would like to find the duplicates (ie the patients that were discharged and then readmitted), change the admission and discharge variable names (to `adm_time_1` & `dc_time_1`), and create a new variable for the second admission and discharge times (to `adm_time_2` & `dc_time_2`). Then I would like to remove the second admission.

Here is a dummy dataset:

```
    df <- 
      tibble(
        patient_id = c(1, 2, 2, 3),
        sex = c("M", "F", "F", "M"),
        adm_time = c("2022-01-03 14:00:00", "2022-01-09 16:42:00", "2022-01-23 22:30:00", "2022-01-10 12:10:00"),
        dc_time = c("2022-01-12 09:09:00", "2022-01-21 10:08:00", "2022-01-27 09:12:00", "2022-01-14 09:36:00")
  )
```

This produces the following output:
[image]

I would like to move the row with `patient_id == 2` to the second line, producing the following output:
[image]

I have tried to use the `duplicated` function, to identify and rename the new columns, but can't figure out how to combine the 2 admission times. For example, this:

```
library(tidyverse)    
df |> 
    rename(adm_time_1 = `adm_time`, dc_time_1 = `dc_time`)|>
    mutate(adm_time_2 = lubridate::as_datetime(ifelse(duplicated(patient_id, fromLast = 
    TRUE), `adm_time_1`, NA)))
```

will select out the duplicated patient ids, but only gives the admission times for the first admission time.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
df %>%
  group_by(patient_id) %>%
  mutate(adm_time = list(adm_time), dc_time = list(dc_time)) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  unnest_wider(c(adm_time, dc_time), names_sep = "_")

  patient_id sex   adm_time_1          adm_time_2          dc_time_1   dc_time_2
       <dbl> <chr> <chr>               <chr>               <chr>       <chr>    
1          1 M     2022-01-03 14:00:00 NA                  2022-01-12… NA       
2          2 F     2022-01-09 16:42:00 2022-01-23 22:30:00 2022-01-21… 2022-01-…
3          3 M     2022-01-10 12:10:00 NA                  2022-01-14… NA
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat! I didn't put it in the dummy dataset, but there were other variables (such as age, weight, admission diagnosis) that I would like to keep in the dataset that were discarded with the above code. How would I keep them in?

Comment: ah! apologies. I'll change it now update:done

Comment: No need to apologise, I didn't specify it in the post. Using distinct() didn't work.

Comment: what do you mean? does the code not work? it seems to work for me

Comment: It works as before, but the other columns are removed from the dataset. All that I have in my dataset (with an additional 20 variables) are the patient_id and the 2 lots of admission and discharge times.

Comment: that's quite odd! Can you add it to your question? I'm not able to reproduce that problem

Comment: I can't reproduce it either! It works well for my dummy dataset with added variables, but not my actual dataset. I'll have a look and let you know. Thanks for your replies. I appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks Mark. The reason was I was generating admission duration as a variable, and when a patient was readmitted, they weren't the same duration as the previous admission. Hence, they weren't identical rows, and distinct() didn't delete them. It's working great now!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively with `pivot_wider`

```r
df %>% mutate(row=row_number(), .by=c(patient_id, sex)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(patient_id, sex), names_from = row, values_from = c(adm_time,dc_time))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  patient_id sex   adm_time_1          adm_time_2          dc_time_1         dc_time_2
       <dbl> <chr> <chr>               <chr>               <chr>             <chr>    
1          1 M     2022-01-03 14:00:00 <NA>                2022-01-12 09:09… <NA>     
2          2 F     2022-01-09 16:42:00 2022-01-23 22:30:00 2022-01-21 10:08… 2022-01-…
3          3 M     2022-01-10 12:10:00 <NA>                2022-01-14 09:36… <NA>
```